# Search for rows in the Sqlite database that contain certain words

Tags: django, sqlite

I was making a killboard for EVE online and wanted to do a database search for certain words contained in the string.
Here are all the column names of my database:
id
final_blow_name
final_blow_ship_type
victim_name
victim_corporation
victim_birthday
victim_gender
victim_security_status
victim_ship_type
sistem_security_status
attackers_len

I did it using LIKE and WHERE. But it gives the error "no such column: the name I was looking for".
Here is my code:

```
    path = 'C:/Users/mrjol/PycharmProjects/myboard/board_veiw/database.db'
    connection = sqlite3.connect(path)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    search_request = str(request.session.pop('search_request', 'None'))
    character_name_1 = search_request.partition(' ')[0]
    character_name_2 = search_request.partition(' ')[2]
    if character_name_2 != '':
        search_request = character_name_1 + '_' + character_name_2
    search_answer = cursor.execute('SELECT final_blow_name FROM Killmails WHERE final_blow_name = Cosmo_Blink')
    connection.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here `search_answer = cursor.execute('SELECT final_blow_name FROM Killmails WHERE final_blow_name = Cosmo_Blink')`. Syntactically, sql is looking for a *column* named `Cosmo_Blink`. Use parameter substitution (binding) as described [in the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#how-to-guides).